# Binary Classification Propensity Scoring: High Accuracy in Train/Validation/Test, but Low Accuracy on Production Data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, boosting

Before I describe my problem, if anyone has material for propensity scoring I would love it if you posted some. I've done a lot of research on propensity, but I think I've bled myself dry on the net. If you guys have any hidden gems I would love for you to send them over. If you guys see anything wrong with how I'm going about predicting the propensity for the model, let me know.

**Task**: The goal is to predict the probability that person A is a good option to be enrolled in a service/product they are currently not enrolled in.

**Approach**: After a lot of research, I decided to create a XGBoost binary classification model and use predict_proba to determine propensity scores. To determine how well my model looks during training and testing, I'm using a confusion matrix and the ROC method. I run CV during training/testing.

**Feature Selection**: I'm using a library I found online called Feature Selector, which prunes through input features for single value columns, high correlation, etc.

**Some Confusion**: Since the goal here is to recommend people who are not currently enrolled in a service, wouldn't I almost be looking for the model to guess incorrectly? To clarify, I want the model to predict true for someone who is false, and grab the probability of how certain the model is about that suggestion. This could also mean the confusion matrix would look very skewed.

**Unbalanced Data**: I'm working on a binary classification model that is relatively imbalanced. The data set is about 80,000 class 0, and 20,000 class 1. I chose to limit my training and test to 80% of the size of class 1 because it is the limiting feature, and down sample class 0 to match it for a balanced model.

I ended up with a randomly sampled train/validation/test set of 16,000 class 1 and 16,000 class 0 (for a total of 32,000 in my train/validation/test set). The accuracy is around 70% in train/validation, and similar in test. I don't see any place where my test could have bled into the training, so I think I'm good on that end.

However, when I try to apply my model to the rest of the data (remaining 68,000), the confusion matrix is suddenly very bad. I have some thoughts about why this would happen. It could just be that there is so much more class 0 than class 1 that the model could not have generalized well.

**My Thoughts**: It could also be possible that the model is truly recommending people who are not currently enrolled to be enrolled. It would make sense then that accuracy would drop since the goal of this project is to find people who are not enrolled, and suggest them for enrollment. How would I best interpret my results?

Any ideas what I can do here?

Comment: Just FYI, this doesn't appear to be about propensity scores as typically defined in statistics and epidemiology, which are a data reduction tool used in estimating the causal effect of an exposure on an outcome. You seem to just want to generate a predictive model to predict enrollment.

Comment: Yes, thank you that is the ultimate goal. What I really want from the model is for it to predict for someone's likelihood of enrollment (binary classification), but I also want how strongly the classifier believes this person would enroll. That way I could suggest the top 5 people who are suggested for enrollment.

Comment: What is the difference between the model predicting a high likelihood of enrollment and the classifier strongly believing a person would enroll? It seems like the classification predicted probability does the job. These are outputted from most classification algorithms (e.g., boosting, random forests, etc.).

Comment: It seems like you want to know for which people a nudge toward enrollment will have the highest return. This is a much tougher question without any nudging having occurred in the data. If you could randomly assign nudges to some people and not to others and then model the probability of enrollment, you might be able to see for what kind of people the nudge is most effect (e.g., raises their probability of enrollment by the highest amount, or moves them closest to almost certain enrollment).

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense. It seems like I would have to run some sort of campaign and get back the response rates of individuals/enrollment rates based on the "nudging" to train the data some more. I am currently using the probability scores from predict_proba, so I think we are on the same page there. Thanks for the advice... I feel more comfortable moving forward

Comment: Glad to be of help :)